# GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MniHjPM HTTP/1.1

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I have a simple Flask chat application that I am testing out coming from a tutorial. Supposedly I just need to run it using the "python app.py" command but when I access it via http://localhost:5000 i get a continuous message of this:

[image: Console]

I was hoping to get 200. I have Flask, Flask-SocketIO, and eventlet already installed. Any idea that can point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The current release of Flask-SocketIO has stricter requirements with regards to cross-origin requests. 
adding `cors_allowed_origins='https://localhost` will resolve the error. 
   i.e.
`SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins="http://localhost")` or  
 
`SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins="*")` hopefully this work.

Comment: yay! it worked. this is the correct answer. thank you so much.

Comment: hi, @Mamun, I still have the same issue. I added cors_allowed_origin but still I am getting continous messages as shown in the question:/ Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

The code from the Flask-SocketIO documentation also produced the same error for me.
However this example code did not (also in debug mode): https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO

In both, the fix above is not included.
Changing the HTML script tags helped.

From:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```