# "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" error

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

Hi I have following flask socketio code

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret'

async_mode=None
socketio = SocketIO(app,async_mode=async_mode,cors_allowed_origins="*")

app.debug = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return 'Welcome!'

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print('Client Connected')

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=3000)
```

And I am connecting to this flask-socket io server from flutter using the following code

```
//using socket-io-client

IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://192.16x.x.x:3000/', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket']
});

socket.onConnect((_) {
   print('connect');
});

socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('disconnect'));
```

But whenever I try to connect, I am getting these loads of unwanted messages on server side.

```
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 195 0.000995
(9784) accepted ('192.168.100.1', 58740)
192.168.100.1 - - [24/May/2021 22:58:15] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 195 0.000997
(9784) accepted ('192.16x.x.x', 58744)
192.168.100.1 - - [24/May/2021 22:58:20] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 195 0.000995
(9784) accepted ('192.16x.x.x', 58747)
192.168.100.1 - - [24/May/2021 22:58:25] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 195 0.000996
(9784) accepted ('192.16x.x.x', 58750)
192.168.100.1 - - [24/May/2021 22:58:30] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 195 0.000996
```

I saw this post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397269/get-socket-io-eio-3transport-pollingt-mnihjpm-http-1-1) and used that cors allow parameter in socketio code but still I cannot get rid of these messages. Also the server nor the client side prints 'connected' or nething one connect, so i am assuming the socket connection didn't happen. So how do I fix this? anyone?

Comment: Hi, did you solved this? I have this exact problem